# R error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'integer'

Tags: r

I'm getting an error in my R program that says:

**Error in as.integer(iter.max) :
cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'integer'**

Here is my code

```
chori <- numeric(20)
for (k in 1:20) {
  kf <- kmeans(whs2018annexBdatscl,k,nstart=20)
  chori[k] <- (kf$betweenss/(k-1))/(kf$tot.withinss/(nrow(whs2018annexBdatscl)-k))
}
plot(2:20,chori[-1],type = "b", lwd= 2, pch= 19, xlab="K", ylab ="CH index", ylim=range(chori[-1])*c(1/2,1))
for ( i in 1:10 ) {
  chrnd = numeric()
  chsmpl = numeric()
  for ( k in 2:20 ) {
    krnd = kmeans(whs2018annexBdatscl,2,function(x)runif(length(x),min(x),max(x),k,nstart=20))
    chrnd[k] = (krnd$betweenss/(k-1)) / (krnd$tot.withinss/(nrow(whs2018annexBdatscl)-k))
    ksmpl = kmeans(apply(whs2018annexBdatscl,2,sample),k,nstart=20)
    chsmpl[k] = (ksmpl$betweenss/(k-1)) / (ksmpl$tot.withinss/(nrow(whs2018annexBdatscl)-k))
  }
  points(2:20,chrnd[-1],type="l",col="red")
  points(2:20,chsmpl[-1],type="l",col="blue")
}
```

The task is to plot CH Index.

Please what am I missing?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What does the `traceback()` show after the error?

Comment: The `iter.max` argument of `kmeans` is the number of iterations but you pass `function(x)runif(length(x),min(x),max(x),k,nstart=20)` which I am not sure what you are trying to do (and the `runif` call is weird as well)